# reglas para imperativo afirmativo + pronombre en la segunda persona del plural

Tags: pronombres, conjugación

Mi novia me ayuda bastante con el español pues es de España, pero como ella no ha estudiado para ser profesora hay algunas reglas de gramática que no conoce. Estos dias le pregunté como yo debería decir si quisiera dar una orden para varias personas para que se lleven algo, en mi cabeza seria algo como "llevad + os + lo = llevadoslo", pero ella me dijo que no, lo cierto es "lleváoslo", le pregunté porque y ella no sabia responderme.

Entonces os pregunto, siempre que hay un verbo en en imperativo de la segunda persona del plural + el pronombre "os" ¿le quitamos la D? ¿es así solamente con el pronombre "os" o con algún otro? ¿cómo es esta regla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, efectivamente, [como dice la Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/imperativo-983/). El imperativo de la segunda persona del plural pierde la -d final cuando se le pospone el pronombre enclítico *os*. Esto ocurre solo en la segunda persona del plural y solo con el pronombre *os*: *llevaos*, *moveos*, *llevadme*, *movedlo*.

La [única excepción](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/idos-mejor-que-iros/) es el verbo **ir**. Para este verbo, el resultado de la adición del pronombre *os* al imperativo *id* es *idos* y no **íos*.

Comment: muchas gracias!